# Show that in a group of seventeen people, there exists a trio who are either three mutual friends, three mutual enemies, or three mutual strangers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose that in a group of people that any two people are either friends, enemies of strangers. Show that in a group of seventeen people, there exists a trio who are either three mutual friends, three mutual enemies, or three mutual strangers.

I know I need to use the Generalized Pigeonhole Principle in some way, but I don't know how to turn this into a proof. I assume one of the seventeen to be A for example, then I have sixteen left, group them into three, so the ceiling of $\frac{16}{3}$ which gives me 6. But I don't know how to use 6 to make the proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A has either 6 friends, 6 enemies or 6 strangers.  If any two of the six have the matching acquaintance level, you have your three.
Otherwise, the six mutually have only two acquaintance levels, and you do Pigeonhole again.

Comment: How do I know if the two of the six have the matching acquaintance level or not?

Comment: If A has six friends, you check whether any two of them are friends with each other.  If A has six enemies, check whether any two are enemies with each other.  The same with strangers.  (You don't actually check, but you do know that either a trio includes A; or you have a group of six of which none are friends with each other.  Now do a smaller Pigeonhole Principle with six people and stranger/enemy instead of 17 people and friend/stranger/enemy.